# Rails using puma, change localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I have developed a rails 5 application that works fine in http://localhost:3000/

Now, I need that this application starts in localhost:3000/example, and that links goes through this new host, (localhost:3000/example/users/new for example). I have got that assets and javascripts works fine in localhost:3000/example with:

```
config.root_path = '/example'
```

but links still redirects to the old one (for example, localhost:3000/users/new).

Anyone know how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your entire routes configurations in a `scope`

```
#config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
   scope '/example' do
     #all the routes goes here
   end
end
```

you can change how assets delivery path with this

for more info : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

```rb
#config/application.rb

config.action_controller.asset_host = "example.com"
config.assets.prefix = '/example'
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.3/configuring.html#configuring-action-controller

Comment: That works with links, but now the assets have been dissapeared again

Comment: So how you are using the assets ? `asset_url("pattern.png", image)` would resolve it the actual assets url.

Comment: @antoniovazquez, i have updated my answer. please let me know if that fixed your issue.

Comment: Hi! That works! configuring application.rb assets are working now. Now a new problem calling methods (error 405). Thanks for all, now looking for new information