# Rails - Method not allowed when executing POST methods (error 405)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, puma, http-status-code-405

I come from this post:
[Rails using puma, change localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073700/rails-using-puma-change-localhost3000-to-localhost3000-example)

I have fixed this issue, but now I receive "Method not allowed" when I do a post request. I have been reading and tried this solution:
[Post returns 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412688/post-returns-405-method-not-allowed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I know where is the problem: If I put in application.rb lines 1- and 2-, all assets are shown correctly and post methods aren't doing it. If I comment these lines, methods works but assets don't.

Application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
    config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses["BadTaste"] = :bad_request

    1- config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://www.sevilla.org"
    2- config.assets.prefix = '/autorizaciones-movilidad'
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    #resources :assets, path: '/autorizaciones-movilidad'
    scope "/autorizaciones-movilidad" do
      get 'vehicles/new'
      get 'vehicles/create'
      ...
      get 'vehicles/update'
    end
end
```

Controller structure:
[image: controller]

Don't know how to solve it.

It is deployed with a proxy server (in localhost it was working ok)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably long since solved this or moved on, but here we go.

One thing to consider is that with Rails, you may get a 405 error when you should get a 404.

I was trying to make a POST call to http://localhost:3000/get_estimate, but in the endpoint file the route was '/estimate' not '/get_estimate', which did not exist.

Looking at the above code, it is possible you made a POST call to

```
localhost:3000/autorizaciones-movilidadvehicles/new
```

instead of

```
localhost:3000/autorizaciones-movilidad/vehicles/new
```

note the '/' right before 'vehicles' in the second URL, which is missing in the first. This could get you a 405 instead of the more accurate 404.